# Applying a time limit to Try

Tags: android, try-catch

I have a try catch and wondered if it is possible to apply a limit on the amount of time the try will try and execute.  If the try cannot execute after say 3 seconds then the catch will invoke.

Thanks

Comment: but what is inside the try? time sensitive functions have timeout methods i guess

Comment: before the `try{}catch{}` block get the system time in milliseconds and put the block in a `while` loop, where the currrent systime will be gotten. then the condition for breaking out the `while` loop will be `if (systime + 3000) //paseudo code`.

Comment: you're misunderstanding Try-Catch.  A try statement begins a block, within which if an exception is thrown, execution flow will move to the catch block (assuming that you catch the correct exception(s).  There is no concept of time or "retry".  You could create a Timer which expires after 3 seconds and creates an exception, cancelling the timer if the condition you are looking for becomes true.  All that said, what are you trying to do?  There is probably a better solution because without knowing the aim, this smells ugly.

Comment: You're talking about some higher level logic, which the try-catch block doesn't implement. Please describe your specific problem and paste some code.